# Please help on this Invariant Problem on Authur Engel's Problem Solving Strategies

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, invariant-theory

I'm reading the solution to this problem but got stuck, I shall post the problem along with the solution below and will point out where I do not understand.

Problem: Suppose not all four integers $a, b, c, d$ are equal, start with $(a, b, c, d)$ and repeatedly replace $(a, b, c, d)$ by  $(a - b, b - c, c - d, d - a)$. Prove that at least one number of the quadruple will become arbitrary large.

Solution:

Let $P_{n} = (a_{n}, b_{n}, c_{n}, d_{n})$ be the quadruple after $n$ iterations, then we have $a_{n} + b_{n} + c_{n} + d_{n} = 0$ for $n≥1$. A very important function for point $P_{n}$ in 4-dimensional space is the square of its distance from the origin $(0,0,0,0)$, which is $a^2_{n} + b^2_{n} + c^2_{n} + d^2_{n}$. If we can prove that it has no upper bound, we would be finished.

We try to find a relation between $P_{n+1}$ and $P_{n}$. Hence,

$a^2_{n+1} + b^2_{n+1} + c_{n+1}^2 + d_{n+1}^2 = (a_{n} - b_{n})^2 + (b_{n} - c_{n})^2 + (c_{n} - d_{n})^2 + (d_n - a_n)^2 
= 2(a^2_n + b^2_n + c^2_n + d^2_n) - 2a_{n}b_{n}  - 2b_{n}c_{n} - 2c_{n}d_{n}  - 2d_{n}a_{n}.\tag{1}$

Now, since $a_{n} + b_{n} + c_{n} + d_{n} = 0$, then

$0 = (a_{n} + b_{n} + c_{n} + d_{n})^2 = (a_n + c_n)^2  + (b_n + d_n)^2 + 2a_{n}b_n + 2a_{n}d_n + 2b_{n}c_n + 2c_{n}d_n.\tag{2}$

Okay, I under the steps above, what what I don't understand is this:

Adding (1) and (2) for $a^2_{n+1} + b^2_{n+1} + c_{n+1}^2 + d^2_{n+1}$ we get

$2(a^2_n + b^2_n + c^2_n + d^2_n) + (a_n + c_n)^2 + (b_n + d_n)^2 ≥ 2(a^2_n + b^2_n + c^2_n + d^2_n).\tag{3}$

From this invariant relationship, we conclude for $n≥2$

$a^2_n + b^2_n + c^2_n + d^2_n ≥ 2^{n-1}(a^2_1 + b^2_1 + c^2_1 + d^2_1) . \tag{4}$

Hence, the distance of the point $P_n$ from origin increases without bound, which means that at least one of the component will become arbitrary large.

Okay, I understand (1) and (2) but I don't understand how he obtained (3) and (4). Please someone should provide detailed explanation on the author obtained (3) and (4). Thanks in advance.

Comment: The RHS of (2) should be $(a_n+c_n)^2+(b_n+d_n)^2+\cdots$.

Comment: I wrote it exactly how it was written in the book. @Lord

Comment: @Icosahedron If so, there is a mistake in the book! You had $0 = (a_{n} + b_{n} + c_{n} + d_{n})^2 = (a_n + b_n)^2  + (b_n + c_n)^2 + 2a_{n}b_n + 2a_{n}d_n + 2b_{n}c_n + 2c_{n}d_n$. Suppose $a=b=0$ but $c=1$ and $d=-1$. Then the RHS would be $0^2 + 1^2 +0+0+0 - 2 = -1$ which clearly would be wrong. See my answer for the right version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, there is an error in (2); you should have something like
$$0 = ((a+c)+(b+d))^2 = (a+c)^2+(b+d)^2 + 2(a+c)(b+d)$$
giving
$$(a+c)^2+(b+d)^2 = -2ab-2ad-2cb-2cd$$
But the RHS here is exactly what appeared in (1).

So substituting (2) into (1) gives
$$a^2_{n+1} + b^2_{n+1} + c^2_{n+1} + d^2_{n+1} = 2 (a^2_{n} + b^2_{n} + c^2_{n} + d^2_{n}) + (a_n+c_n)^2+(b_n+d_n)^2$$

But squares are always non-negative so
$$a^2_{n+1} + b^2_{n+1} + c^2_{n+1} + d^2_{n+1} \ge 2 (a^2_{n} + b^2_{n} + c^2_{n} + d^2_{n})$$
which is (3).

Then by induction or similar, it follows that 
$$\begin{align}
a^2_{n+1} + b^2_{n+1} + c^2_{n+1} + d^2_{n+1}
&\ge 2 (a^2_{n} + b^2_{n} + c^2_{n} + d^2_{n}) \\
&\ge 2 \cdot 2 (a^2_{n-1} + b^2_{n-1} + c^2_{n-1} + d^2_{n-1}) \\
& \ge \cdots \\
& \ge 2^{n} (a^2_{1} + b^2_{1} + c^2_{1} + d^2_{1}) \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: What you did in the last step is called upfolding right?

Comment: By upfolding, I mean plugging in.

Comment: Interesting - I don't know what one might actually call the sort of argument I've presented instead of induction (which would normally be how one would make the argument)! Perhaps one might say it's an *algorithm*: if you repeat the operation that goes from the 1st to 2nd line a further $n-2$ times, you arrive at the bottom line.

Comment: "Plugging in" means the same as "substituting in". I would also say that, from a rigorous point of view, proving that this algorithmic process gives the result at the bottom would still be done with induction. But it's so obvious one might not bother.

Comment: please can you explain this in more detail "Perhaps
one might say it's an algorithm: if you repeat the operation that goes from the
1st to 2nd line a further times, you arrive at the bottom line. "

Also, please explain how to prove it by induction since it's not so obvious to me, Thanks.

Comment: I just mean you have an argument that means $(\cdots)_{n+1} \ge 2 (\cdots)_{n}$ (for any $n$) so you keep doing that repeatedly and you end up at the bottom line. For induction, write down the statement you want to prove for general $n$, check the $n=0$ case, and then work out what the inductive step is. Ask a new question if you can't do it when you've had a try.